# Rails 3 finding object in a HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Have myself confused . . .

I have a SubscriptionPlan ActiveRecord object which has an HABTM to available_to_roles.

In Rails 3 I'm trying to create a scope or class method on SubscriptionPlan to get appropriate subscription plans:

def self.available_subscription_plans(users_roles)  #users_roles = Array of roles
  #query to find all subscription plans where available_to_roles is in users_roles
end

Having a very hard time figuring out the most appropriate way to do this with the new syntax.

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusion was due to a typo in the relationship definition and low text contrast.  Answer for anybody coming along later:

```
class SubscriptionPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :available_to_roles, :join_table => "[join_table_name]", :class_name => 'UserRole'

  scope :available_subscription_plans, lambda { |users_roles|
    joins(:available_to_roles)
    .where("user_roles.id IN ( ? ) AND CURRENT_DATE > active_from_date AND CURRENT_DATE < active_to_date", users_roles)}
end
```